# What is this operator <> in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm currently working with a sample of code which has the following part:

```
HAVING p.product_id <> ". $product['product_id'] ."
```

I haven't yet come accross <> I have tried to look this up but can not find a simple answer.

Comment: It is the same as `!=`

Comment: It means "not equals to", an equivalent of `!=`.

Comment: I believed it might be as thats what the purpose of the code was, is there any differences in using != or <>?

Comment: I think it's just user preference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to juergen d and Terry for provide the answer of:

"It is the same as !" and "It means "not equals to", an equivalent of !=."